# how to set default navigation bar color, text color for all view controller nav bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have 12 view controllers with navigation bar.But i need to declar at one place for navigation bar color to green , and all titile text, bar button color to black .So for all my view controller i need tp set this two condition.

But when i set for some view controller , its not working fully for all view controller.I tried below code :

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

But , how to code in one place that should apply for all screen ?? I am using swift 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIAppearance` object. Here you can find a quick tutorial to manage it: http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/

Anyway, just call the class method `appearance()` of `UINavigationBar` like this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().YOUR_PROPERTY = YOUR_VALUE
```

Try to call it in the `AppDelegate` since it should have to be executed before you display any `UINavigationBar`

Comment: so , i have to declare the  `UINavigationBar.appearance().YOUR_PROPERTY = YOUR_VALUE` to my appdelegate for all property.Like nav bar color, text color...Am i right??

Comment: Better practise is to write code in ViewWillAppear in every viewController.

Comment: I do not agree with @SharmaVishal . If you want to override the color, you can do it, but there's no need to do the same thing on N-controller when you can set these properties once

Comment: If you prsent Other controllers from Library or anyWhere then It may affect on your app.

Comment: The controllers you'll present will have the same style you defined via `UIAppearance` object. I can't understand what you mean @SharmaVishal